# mysql trigger operand should contain 2 columns

Tags: mysql, decimal-point, mysql-error-1241

My trigger looks like this:

```
begin
IF ((NEW.tgebucht >= NEW.tteilnmax) AND (NEW.tgebucht!=0) AND (OLD.tstatus=0)) THEN
  SET NEW.tstatus = 1;
ELSEIF ((NEW.tgebucht < NEW.tteilnmax) AND (OLD.tstatus=1)) THEN
  SET NEW.tstatus =0;
END IF;
IF ((0,25*NEW.tteilnmax)>=(NEW.tteilnmax-NEW.tgebucht)) THEN
    SET NEW.trestplatze =1;
END IF;
end
```

And I am getting an error like this:

```
Operand should contain 2 column(s)
```

I am not really sure why, I know it is related to second if but I can't configure where, does anyone has an idea what to change? Am I doing something wrong here? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax looks well. But there is a hidden bug in next line -

```
IF ((0,25*NEW.tteilnmax)>=(NEW.tteilnmax-NEW.tgebucht)) THEN
```

You should use '.' as a point delimiter -

```
IF ((0.25*NEW.tteilnmax)>=(NEW.tteilnmax-NEW.tgebucht)) THEN
```

Comment: LOL, now i am laughing at myself, because I tried this one hour ago and it didn't work and than I changed the syntax and forgot to change that, ha ha, thanx a lot :)

Comment: @julie smith Welcome)